# Add a text binned column to a long format dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a long format data table as shown below:

| Well | Date | Type | Variable | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1/1/2023 | current | Oil_Fcst | 20 |
| A | 1/2/2023 | current | Oil_Fcst | 100 |
| A | 1/1/2023 | prev | Oil_Fcst_Prev | 25 |
| A | 1/2/2023 | prev | Oil_Fcst_Prev | 50 |
| A | 1/1/2023 | current | Gas_Fcst | 50 |
| A | 1/2/2023 | current | Gas_Fcst | 100 |
| A | 1/1/2023 | prev | Gas_Fcst_Prev | 25 |
| A | 1/2/2023 | prev | Gas_Fcst_Prev | 50 |

I want to add a new column titled "**Phase**" and define "**Oil**" to "Oil-related variable" and "**Gas**" to "Gas related variable" as:

| Well | Date | Type | Variable | Value | Phase |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1/1/2023 | current | Oil_Fcst | 20 | Oil |
| A | 1/2/2023 | current | Oil_Fcst | 100 | Oil |
| A | 1/1/2023 | prev | Oil_Fcst_Prev | 25 | Oil |
| A | 1/2/2023 | prev | Oil_Fcst_Prev | 50 | Oil |
| A | 1/1/2023 | current | Gas_Fcst | 50 | Gas |
| A | 1/2/2023 | current | Gas_Fcst | 100 | Gas |
| A | 1/1/2023 | prev | Gas_Fcst_Prev | 25 | Gas |
| A | 1/2/2023 | prev | Gas_Fcst_Prev | 50 | Gas |

Is there a way to explicitly define the column based on the "Variable" column values?

Answer (score 0):

Using `strsplit` on `"_"` and selecting `1`<sup>st</sup> elements.

```
> dat |> cbind(Phase=sapply(strsplit(dat$Variable, '_'), `[`, 1))
  Well     Date    Type      Variable Value Phase
1    A 1/1/2023 current      Oil_Fcst    20   Oil
2    A 1/2/2023 current      Oil_Fcst   100   Oil
3    A 1/1/2023    prev Oil_Fcst_Prev    25   Oil
4    A 1/2/2023    prev Oil_Fcst_Prev    50   Oil
5    A 1/1/2023 current      Gas_Fcst    50   Gas
6    A 1/2/2023 current      Gas_Fcst   100   Gas
7    A 1/1/2023    prev Gas_Fcst_Prev    25   Gas
8    A 1/2/2023    prev Gas_Fcst_Prev    50   Gas
```

---

*Data:*

```
> dput(dat)
structure(list(Well = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A"
), Date = c("1/1/2023", "1/2/2023", "1/1/2023", "1/2/2023", "1/1/2023", 
"1/2/2023", "1/1/2023", "1/2/2023"), Type = c("current", "current", 
"prev", "prev", "current", "current", "prev", "prev"), Variable = c("Oil_Fcst", 
"Oil_Fcst", "Oil_Fcst_Prev", "Oil_Fcst_Prev", "Gas_Fcst", "Gas_Fcst", 
"Gas_Fcst_Prev", "Gas_Fcst_Prev"), Value = c(20L, 100L, 25L, 
50L, 50L, 100L, 25L, 50L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-8L))
```

Comment: thnx. What if there are other column values with a different structure to the naming. For example, 'Increment_oil_uplift', 'increment_oil_uplift_prev', 'increment_gas_uplift', 'increment_gas_uplift_prev'..

Comment: You would select the `2`nd element, Try a single `strsplit("'Increment_oil_uplift'", "_")`. I.e. `dat |> cbind(Phase=sapply(strsplit(dat$Variable, '_'), `[`, 2))`. I the parts are not always nth element, we'd need a different approach.

Answer (score 0):

Please try

```r
df$phase <- sub("_.*", "", df$Variable)

df$phase <- str_remove_all(df$Variable, "(_.*)")

[1] "Oil" "Oil" "Oil" "Oil" "Gas" "Gas" "Gas" "Gas"
```